# The decomposition of a meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to solve the following problem, taken from the book of T.W Gamelin,  Complex Analysis, so it goes like this:

Suppose $f(z)$ is a meromorphic on the disk $\{|z|<s \}$ with only a finite number of poles in the disk. Show that the Laurent decomposition of $f(z)$ with respect to the annulus $\{s-\epsilon<|z|<s \}$ has the form $f(z)=f_0(z)+f_1(z)$, where $f_1(z)$ is the sum of the principal parts of $f(z)$ at its poles.

My idea is to assume that   $f_1(z)$ is the sum of the principal parts of $f(z)$ at its poles, but I don't know if this could help me, because then I don't know what to do there, I have thought to use the uniqueness of the Laurent decomposition, but I can't figure out how.

Can you help me to prove the above result please? thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I guess $\epsilon$ is such that all the poles are inside $|z|<s-\epsilon$, isn't it?

We check:

1. $f_1$ is analytic on $|z|>s-\epsilon$ (well, actually analytic everywhere except at the poles of $f$). This is because $f_1$  is rational and its poles are in $|z|<s-\epsilon$.
2. We also have that $f_1(\infty)=0$. This is because $f_1$ is a proper rational function.
3. It remains to check that $f_0=f-f_1$ is analytic in $|z|<s$. It is clear that it is analytic at any of those points that is not a pole of $f$, because there it is a difference of two analytic function. Now, at the poles of $f$ just expand $f$ in Laurent series. You get that $f_0=f-f_1$ has at those point Taylor series, which is the regular part of the Laurent series of $f$.

Comment: Thanks a lot :), so in the  second  part you are using that f is a rational function, How could it be done in general?

Comment: @user162343 What does it mean "in general"? What aspect would be generalized?

Comment: Well is because in your arguments you wrote that $f_1$ is a proper rational function, so how is that? every other case of meromorphism follows from this?

Comment: @user162343 Ah, that is because $f_1$ is the principal part of $f$ and $f$ has only finitely many poles. The principal part at each pole $z=a$ is of the form $Q_a(z)=P\left(\frac{1}{z-a}\right)$, where $P$ is a polynomial. Then $Q_a(z)$ is a proper rational function. Therefore $f_1$ is a finite sum of a few $Q_a(z)$ for the different poles $a$.

Comment: Right, :) jajaja, Now in the last part, you say, expand $f$ in laurent series and you get... Can you explain more that part please ;)

Comment: Say that you want to check that $f_0$ is analytic at $z=a$, where $a$ is a pole of $f$. We can expand $f$ in Laurent series at $z=a$ to get $f=Q_a(z)+R(z)$, where $R(z)$ is analytic at $z=a$. Therefore, when we do $f-f_0$ the $Q_a(z)$ cancels, because it is one of the summands in $f_0$ and all that remain are functions that are analytic at $z=a$, say $R(z)$ and the other summands of $f_0$, which are principal parts but at other poles.

Comment: Ok, let me do something, I check this (because I got to go to a seminary), and if I got some question, Can I let you know a bit later?

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: I am back @Alamos, so we have that $f_0=R(z)+Q_{a}(z)-Q_{a}(z)=Q_{a}(z)+R(z)-Q_{a}(z)=R(z)$ then what other summands of $f_0 $ are left?

Comment: No, $$f_1=\sum_{a\text{ pole of f}}Q_a,$$ and $$f=Q_{a_0}+R.$$ Then $$f_0=f-f_1=Q_{a_0}+R-\sum_{a\text{ pole of f}}Q_a=R-\sum_{a_0\neq a\text{ pole of f}}Q_a.$$ In the right-hand side all functions are analytic at $a_0$.

Comment: Ok, then $R(z)$ is an auxiliary function that is analytic right?

Comment: Or R(z) is the part of the expansion the the positive powers, as a power series?

Comment: $R$ is the regular part (yes, the non-negative powers in the power series expansion) of the Laurent expansion of $f$ at $a_0$. Actually, for make the notation precise we should write $R_{a_0}$, because it depends on the point at which we are expanding.

Comment: Right, so let me resume, we need to assume that $f_1$ is the sum of all the principal parts to begin working, so we have 1), 2) because of the properties of $f_1$ as a rational function , Now for 3), we need to check (by the laurent decomposition theorem ) that $f_0$ is analytic at $|z|<s$ so we expand $f$ and we have that the principal part in the pole $a_0$ is canceled so $f_0$ is a function that is analytic in the pole $z=a$ and we are done right?